# facebook ad cant' load in sdk version 5.+

Tags: android, facebook-android-sdk, interstitial, facebook-audience-network

> i have create facebook ad demo app, but can't load any ad(Interstitial ,Native ,Banner) in any version sdk.

if i using sdk version 5.3.0 then facebook ad return error.

> Error: New bundles must use latest available Audience Network SDK.

[image]

if i using sdk version 5.5.0,5.6.0 then facebook ad return error.

> Error: No fill

[image]

> i also tried live ad id(264476213973610_264482430639655) and testing ad id (YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID) but doesn't work

```
 AudienceNetworkAds.initialize(this);
    final InterstitialAd interstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(MainActivity.this, "YOUR_PLACEMENT_ID");
    AdSettings.addTestDevice("6f2e675e-05b0-46d8-b3d6-032ef6a25fdb");
    interstitialAd.destroy();
    interstitialAd.setAdListener(new InterstitialAdListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDisplayed(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad displayed.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onInterstitialDismissed(Ad ad) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Interstitial ad dismissed.");
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(Ad ad, AdError adError) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error: " + adError.getErrorMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdLoaded(Ad ad) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Loaded: " + ad.getPlacementId(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            interstitialAd.show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClicked(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad clicked!");
        }

        @Override
        public void onLoggingImpression(Ad ad) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Interstitial ad impression logged!");
        }
    });

    interstitialAd.loadAd();
```

Comment: Have u got any solution?

Comment: @SumitShukla change sdk version 5.11.0

Comment: I have used like this com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.+ . Will try your solution! Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I had faced a similar issue. So I'll explain how I solved it.

To test properly on your device, you need to follow some other steps too other than you mentioned in the question.

STEPS:

1. Properly follow the interstitial, banner, etc. documentation to integrate ads
2. Download the official Facebook app (which is required to get test ads) and log in using either tester's account or Admin's account of the Audience Network. FB doesn't return ads if it doesn't find its official app on the device because it crawls the data of the account to provide the relevant ads to the user
3. Add test device to get test ads (or live ads for testing which doesn't give you revenue). To add a device:

   i) Login to your Audience Network account

   ii) Go to *Monetization Manager > Integration > Testing*

   iii) Add test device using Android's AAID or iOS's IDFA. You can check other SO's threads to find AAID or IDFA of the device, in case you don't know.

   iv) You can test it in the device now and you must be getting ads. If still there are no ads, select *Use real advertiser content* option there itself. Now to test different type of ads like HD Video, Simple Image or such; Click *Select Ad Type* on the same screen

NOTE: Remember to check the article on [FAN's ad Caching in Android 9+](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-network-security-config) because HD Video or any type of video ads won't show on Android 9+ and you might get a blank screen blocking all the functionalities of your app.

Comment: I did everything as mentioned in the docs & u said but ads don't show up! It always shows the option "Integrate the Audience Network SDK into your app" as incompleted.

Answer (score 0):

use sdk version com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.11.0